# Replacing and deleting a character from a string in c++?

Tags: string, c++11

This program is giving wrong output,, basically i want to remove the character specified and replace it by 'g'...For e.g: All that glitters is not gold if the user entered o then the output should be All that glitters is ngt ggld but the program is deleting all the characters from n onwards

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
   string input(" ALL GLItters are not gold");
   char a;
   cin>>a;
   for(int i=0;i<input.size();i++)
   {
     if(input.at(i)==a)
     {
        input.erase(i,i+1);
        input.insert(i,"g");
     }
   }
    cout<<"\n";
   cout<<input;

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string& erase (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos);
```

The second parameter ( len ) is the Number of characters to erase.
You have to put 1 not i+1 :

```
input.erase(i,1);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/

Answer (score 1):

Why not replace it directly? Replace your `for` loop with this:

```
for (char& c : input)
{
    if (c == a)
        c = 'g';
}
```

[Live example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e15c16e1e3e3c513).